# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document which contains 2 other documents. To achieve this task, I use `findOneAndUpdate`, but mongoose throws me a `CastError` (`Cast to ObjectId failed`).

My models:

user.js

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    info: {
        type : Schema.ObjectId,
        required : true,
        ref : 'Info'
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

info.js

```
var infoSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Info', infoSchema);
```

My query:

```
var tmp = {
    email: req.body.email,
    info: {
        name: req.body.info.name
    }
};

User.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.id
}, tmp, {
    upsert: false,
    new: true
}).exec(function(err, doc) {
    /* check errors */
    /* send response */
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Are my models poorly set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed

The type of `info` is `Schema.ObjectId`, whereas one object

```
info: {
    name: req.body.info.name
}
```

is passed into it as `ObjectId`, as result, it failed.

Here maybe one work around.

```
var new_info = new Info({
    firstname: req.body.info.name.firstname, //
    lastname: req.body.info.name.lastname    //     
});

new_info.save(function(err, doc) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        var tmp = {
            email: req.body.email,
            info: doc._id
        }

        User.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, tmp, {
            upsert: false,
            new: true
        }).exec(function(err, doc) {
            //
        });         
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunatly, my id is the good one, I checked.