# "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" when add array of objects to mutation react-graphql-apollo-mongoose

Tags: mongoose, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

I got the `"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"` error only when i add `product` Array of Objects to mutation, if i only add `orderId` Int there is no error. Below are more info:

Schema

```
type Order {
    orderId: Int
    product: [ProductInput]
}

input ProductInput {
    prodId: String
    value: [ValueInput]
}

type Product {
    prodId: String
    value: [Value]
}

type Value{
    name:String,
    props:String
}

input ValueInput{
    name:String,
    props:String
}
```

Mutation

```
 addOrder(orderId: Int, product: [ProductInput]):Order
```

Resolver (with mongoose)

```
 addOrder(parent, args, context, info) {
 let orderId;
 let product;

 if (args.orderId) {
      orderId = { orderId: args.orderId };
      }
 if (args.product) {
      product= { product: args.product};
      }

return context.Order.findOneAndUpdate(
      { orderId: args.orderId },
      {
        $setOnInsert: {
          ...orderId,
          ...product
        }
      },
      { new: true, upsert: true }
    );
}
```

Even I get error, the mutation is successfully in database,but graphql return

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "addOrder"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined",
            "    at EmbeddedDocument.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schema.js:1824:23)",
            "    at VirtualType.applyGetters (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\virtualtype.js:137:25)",
            "    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.get (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:1508:19)",
            "    at applyVirtuals (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:3246:20)",
            "    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.$toObject (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:2986:5)",
            "    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.toObject (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\document.js:3169:15)",
            "    at DocumentArrayPath.cast (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schema\\documentarray.js:401:27)",
            "    at DocumentArrayPath.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1010:12)",
            "    at DocumentArrayPath.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1424:15)",
            "    at DocumentArrayPath.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\schematype.js:1391:17)",
            "    at castUpdateVal (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\castUpdate.js:515:19)",
            "    at walkUpdatePath (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\castUpdate.js:342:22)",
            "    at castUpdate (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\castUpdate.js:99:18)",
            "    at model.Query._castUpdate (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:4481:10)",
            "    at castDoc (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:4509:18)",
            "    at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (C:\\Users\\mihai\\Desktop\\Projects\\ECOM\\BACKEND\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\query.js:3472:22)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "addOrder": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First

> Mutation

```
 addOrder(orderId: Int, product: [ProductInput]):Order
```

**Mutation `addOrder` should return `Order` object**

`findOneAndUpdate` method inserts a new record but returning result is optional - it can be done using  `returnNewDocument: true` (default: `false`) - see [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

### Second

If you're inserting nested/embeded entities - array of ProductInput - you need to insert/create them, too - see [slightly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34889866/6124657) - of course it depends on mongoose schema (you didn't provided).

It's easier to have mongose parts working and 'wrap' with graphql resolvers than adapt/change mongoose schema to reflect grpahql types/resolver changes.

Comment: Hi, `{new:true}` in mongoose i think is same as `returnNewDocument` in mongo. Anyway, i tried using `returnNewDocument` but still got error. Also i tried to create nested entity , also i got the same result (error, but succesfully mutation) : ```  if (args.product) {
      product = {
        product: args.product.map((product) => {
          return {
            prodId: product.prodId,
            variation: product.variation.map((variation) => {
              return { name: variation.name, value: variation.value };
            })
          };
        })
      };
    }```

Comment: actually you are right: i adjusted schema like `product.prodId`, instead of `{product:{prodId:x}}` and i got no error now! Thanks! Also `It's easier to have mongose parts working and 'wrap' with graphql resolvers than adapt/change mongoose schema to reflect grpahql types/resolver changes.` Can you point me to something more detailed? I would love to learn a different and easier method

Comment: it shouldn't be required but probably helps [apollo] in recognizing types - defining `__typename` [for products and variants] property should do the trick ...  show mongoose schema (how is related to graphql types)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @xadm I solved the error via replacing in resolver:

```
 if (args.product) {
      product= { product: args.product};
      }
```

with

```
if (args.product) {
      product = args.product.map((product) => {
        return {
          'product.prodId': product.prodId,
          'product.variation': product.variation.map((variation) => {
            return {
              'product.variation.name': variation.name,
              'product.variation.value': variation.value
            };
          })
        };
      });
    }
```